# Can't run XCTest for a Cocoa Framework with SwiftyJSON dependency

Tags: swift, unit-testing, cocoa, frameworks, dependencies

I am building a dynamic Cocoa Framework (let's say MyFrame) using Swift 1.2 and Xcode 6.4.
I am using SwiftyJSON as a linked framework in MyFrame after downloading it using Carthage. It builds and runs perfectly.
I wrote unit tests in a XCTestCase. The testing target is MyFrameTests. It works perfectly as long as MyFrame does not use SwiftyJSON. When I add SwiftyJSON in MyFrame, I get the following error:

```
2015-08-25 18:22:25.653 xctest[17732:237778] The test bundle at /Users/manonh/try16/MyFrame/DerivedData/MyFrame/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameTests.xctest could not be loaded because an unanticipated error occurred.
2015-08-25 18:22:25.654 xctest[17732:237778] Detailed error information: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “MyFrameTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Users/manonh/try16/MyFrame/DerivedData/MyFrame/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameTests.xctest/MyFrameTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
Referenced from: /Users/manonh/try16/MyFrame/DerivedData/MyFrame/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameTests.xctest/MyFrameTests
Reason: image not found) UserInfo=0x7f8e13705070 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/manonh/try16/MyFrame/DerivedData/MyFrame/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameTests.xctest/MyFrameTests, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/manonh/try16/MyFrame/DerivedData/MyFrame/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameTests.xctest/MyFrameTests): Library not loaded: @rpath/SwiftyJSON.framework/SwiftyJSON
Referenced from: /Users/manonh/try16/MyFrame/DerivedData/MyFrame/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameTests.xctest/MyFrameTests
Reason: image not found, NSBundlePath=/Users/manonh/try16/MyFrame/DerivedData/MyFrame/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyFrameTests.xctest, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “MyFrameTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}

*** Test session exited(1) without checking in. If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /var/folders/9g/jxyyssdx0xn9xp_29fg2l9080000gq/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest-status/Session-2015-08-25_18:22:25-2wDwFh.log
```

I googled this and found some things about defines module and other options in Build Settings > Packaging. Did not work.

I have tried to add `import SwiftyJSON` inside the test swift file. Did not work

I also tried to put SwiftyJSON in Copy Bundle Resource in MyFrame. Did not work

In MyFrameTests, I tried to add SwiftyJSON in Link Binary With Libraries and Copy Bundle Resource. I tried all the combinations of the above "locations" of SwiftyJSON framework. Did not work

After 2 days of struggling and googling and reading other stackoverflow posts, I haven't found a way to run this test.

Is there anyone that knows how to unit test a cocoa framework that has a dependency?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Below is the very basic class I want to test in MyFrame and the testcase in MyFrameTests, if it can be of any use.

**MyFrameClass.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

public class MyFrameClass {

    public init() {}

    public func getFive() -> Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

**MyFrameTests.swift**

```
import UIKit
import XCTest
import MyFrame

class test18Tests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        XCTAssert(true, "Pass")
    }

    func testExample2() {
        var c = MyFrameClass()
        XCTAssertEqual(c.getFive(), 5, "Five test of MyFrameClass")
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        self.measureBlock() {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    } 
}
```

Just remove `import SwiftyJSON` from MyFrameClass.swift and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (not exactly the same though) problem. My swiftyJSON was installed using cocoa pods.
I then removed it form cocoa pods and installed the file manually in my project and that solved the problem. I know I have to manually update that file now, but since it hasn't any dependencies on other frameworks that's fairly easy and a small price to pay

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to include directly the SwiftyJSON.xcodeproj into my workspace and the tests are running. If someone has an idea why including the framework does not work, I would love to know it

Answer (score 0):

- Copy the xcodeproj from SwiftyJSON inside your workspace
- In the buildPhase/link binary with libraries from the test target, add "SwiftyJSON" clicking + and choose from the workspace 
  (you must have the cocoa framework there + the SwiftyJSON framework there)
- Command B
- Command U